# Disable or Enable select Options based on value selected in another select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created 2 select lists that I would like cascading. I mean, if the value x is chosen into the first select, then values x,y,z etc. of second select should be disabled and value w enabled etc.

My following script isn't working. I can select a value into the first select, the correct values are disabled or enabled into the second select, but when I change the value into the first select again, then the same value are still disabled or enabled in the second select :

```js
$('#form').on('change', function() {

  var pl1 = document.getElementById('ordersdetailID_portion').value; // partyloafportionID


  if (pl1 == 1) {

    console.log('ID_portion:', pl1);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="1"]').prop('disabled', false);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="2"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="3"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="4"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="5"]').prop('disabled', true);

  } else if (pl1 == 2) {

    console.log('ID_portion:', pl1);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="1"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="2"]').prop('disabled', false);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="3"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="4"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="5"]').prop('disabled', true);

  } else if (pl1 == 3) {

    console.log('ID_portion:', pl1);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="1"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="2"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="3"]').prop('disabled', false);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="4"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="5"]').prop('disabled', true);

  } else if (pl1 == 4) {

    console.log('ID_portion:', pl1);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="1"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="2"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="3"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="4"]').prop('disabled', false);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="5"]').prop('disabled', false);

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ordersdetailID_portion" name="child-ID_portion" class="form-control select2  select2-hidden-accessible" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" required="">
  <option value="">** Veuillez saisir une option Nombre de sandwiches</option>
  <option value="4">100</option>
  <option value="1">30</option>
  <option value="2">60</option>
  <option value="3">80</option>
</select>

<select id="ordersdetailpartyloafweightID" name="child-partyloafweightID" class="form-control select2  select2-hidden-accessible" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" required="">
  <option value="">** Please choose the appropriate weight</option>
  <option value="2" disabled="">1 Kg</option>
  <option value="3" disabled="">1.5 Kg</option>
  <option value="4">2 Kg</option>
  <option value="5">2.5 Kg</option>
  <option value="1" disabled="">600 g</option>
</select>
```

Comment: If I try this in a fiddle it seems to work right? https://jsfiddle.net/dnwk49bg/ Did you use the form with an id? `<form id="form">`

Comment: Yes it is not the most elegant coding, but it works, but not when I implement this script into a JS include file (Laravel and Adminlte Crudbooster)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)

I am not 100% sure I got the combos right, but this is the method I would use

No need to set the disabled, I simply trigger the change on load

```js
$('#ordersdetailID_portion').on('change', function() {
  var pl1 = +this.value, // partyloafportionID
     $weight = $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID');
  $('option[value="1"]',$weight).prop('disabled', pl1 != 1);
  $('option[value="2"]',$weight).prop('disabled', pl1 != 2);
  $('option[value="3"]',$weight).prop('disabled', pl1 != 3);
  $('option[value="4"]',$weight).prop('disabled', pl1 != 4 && pl1 != 5);
  $('option[value="5"]',$weight).prop('disabled', pl1 != 4 && pl1 != 5);
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ordersdetailID_portion" name="child-ID_portion" class="form-control select2  select2-hidden-accessible" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" required="">
  <option value="">** Veuillez saisir une option Nombre de sandwiches</option>
  <option value="4">100</option>
  <option value="1">30</option>
  <option value="2">60</option>
  <option value="3">80</option>
</select>

<select id="ordersdetailpartyloafweightID" name="child-partyloafweightID" class="form-control select2  select2-hidden-accessible" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" required="">
  <option value="">** Please choose the appropriate weight</option>
  <option value="2">1 Kg</option>
  <option value="3">1.5 Kg</option>
  <option value="4">2 Kg</option>
  <option value="5">2.5 Kg</option>
  <option value="1">600 g</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your script which is so elegant. I tried it in a js include file but doesn't work sadly, no clue why (Laravel 5.4 + Crudbooster based on adminlte). Quite frustrated because I can't find a solution...

Comment: If you place the script before the `</body>` tag it might work better

Answer (score 0):

Your code `document.getElementById('ordersdetailID_portion').value;` returns a `string`, but you are checking for the number.

Also, on each change, you must first reset all the option's `disabled` to `false`. Check code below:

```js
$('form').on('change', function() {
  $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option').prop('disabled', false);
  var pl1 = document.getElementById('ordersdetailID_portion').value; // partyloafportionID

  if (pl1 == "1") {

    console.log('ID_portion:', pl1);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="1"]').prop('disabled', false);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="2"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="3"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="4"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="5"]').prop('disabled', true);

  } else if (pl1 == "2") {

    console.log('ID_portion:', pl1);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="1"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="2"]').prop('disabled', false);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="3"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="4"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="5"]').prop('disabled', true);

  } else if (pl1 == "3") {

    console.log('ID_portion:', pl1);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="1"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="2"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="3"]').prop('disabled', false);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="4"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="5"]').prop('disabled', true);

  } else if (pl1 == "4") {

    console.log('ID_portion:', pl1);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="1"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="2"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="3"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="4"]').prop('disabled', false);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafweightID option[value="5"]').prop('disabled', false);

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select id="ordersdetailID_portion" name="child-ID_portion" class="form-control select2  select2-hidden-accessible" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" required="">
    <option value="">** Veuillez saisir une option Nombre de sandwiches</option>
    <option value="4">100</option>
    <option value="1">30</option>
    <option value="2">60</option>
    <option value="3">80</option>
  </select>

  <select id="ordersdetailpartyloafweightID" name="child-partyloafweightID" class="form-control select2  select2-hidden-accessible" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" required="">
    <option value="">** Please choose the appropriate weight</option>
    <option value="2">1 Kg</option>
    <option value="3">1.5 Kg</option>
    <option value="4">2 Kg</option>
    <option value="5">2.5 Kg</option>
    <option value="1">600 g</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks also to you. I tried it in a js include file but doesn't work sadly, no clue why (Laravel 5.4 + Crudbooster based on adminlte). Quite frustrated because I can't find a solution...